# mklink when using it think path is a command

Tags: windows-8.1, mklink

My first question here. I'm running Windows 8.1 when doing this.

```
cmd mklink /j "d:/project/relx/_build/test/lib/relx/test/rlx_release_SUITE_data/relx-output796596/foo/lib/override_app106921-12.88.71" "d:/project/relx/_build/test/lib/relx/test/rlx_release_SUITE_data/override_dir_101315/override_app106921-12.88.71"
```

I am running this command but when running it I get this response:

```
'elx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

So I guess it think that something in the path is triggering a flag or command.

Comment: `cmd mklink ...` is not a valid command. It should either be just `mklink ...` or `cmd /c mklink ...`

Answer (score 2):

#### 'elx' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

`cmd mklink ...` is not a valid command.

It should either be just `mklink ...` or `cmd /c mklink ...`

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> CMD [charset] [options]
>
> CMD [charset] [options] [/C Command] 
>
> CMD [charset] [options] [/K Command]
> ```
>
> **Options**
>
> ```
> /C     Run Command and then terminate
>
> /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
>        This is useful for testing, to examine variables
>
> Command : The command, program or batch script to be run.
>           This can even be several commands separated with '&' 
>           (the whole should also be surrounded by "quotes")
> ```

Source [CMD.exe - Start a new CMD shell and (optionally) run a command/executable program.](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.